# Converting an integer and a character to a string in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a string comprised of a single letter, followed by 4 digits e.g. b6789. I'm getting stuck when I try to convert a character, and integer to one String. I can't use toString() because I've overwritten it, and I assume that concatenation is not the best way to approach it? This was my solution, until I realised that valueof() only takes a single parameter. Any suggestions?  FYI - I'm using Random, because I will be creating multiples at some point. The rest of my code seemed irrelevant, and hence has been omitted.

```
   Random r = new Random();

   Integer numbers = r.nextInt(9000) + 1000;

   Character letter = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

   String strRep = String.valueOf(letter, numbers);
```

Comment: What's wrong with concatenation? That's exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I read somewhere that it wasn't the best method of approaching it, and valueOf() or toString() were preferred.....I guess though, there is no alternative approach that I can take?

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean for you not to use concatenation with + operator.

Rather than that, there's a class called StringBuilder which will do the trick for you. Just create an empty one, append anything you need on it (takes Objects or primitives as arguments and does all the work for you), and at the end, just call at its "toString()" method, and you'll have your concatenated String.

For example

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Foo");
sb.append(123);
return sb.toString();
```

would return the string Foo123

Comment: Thanks - but what happens if I've overridden toString() so as it returns a more accurate representation of my class?

Comment: for any Object (and not primitive), it calls toString directly, so if you override that, it will use the string representation you coded.

Comment: OK, so that option wouldn't work, unless I removed my overridden toString() method because it currently returns something different

Comment: if you REALLY need to do that, you can always create an extra toHumanReadable() method in your class, and concatenate yourObject.toHumanReadable()

Comment: Ah OK - what is toHumanReadable() ? Would you mind enlightening me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
Character.toString(char)
```

which is

```
String.valueOf(char)
```

in reality which also works.
or just use

```
String str = "" + 'a';
```

as already mentioned but not very efficient as it is

```
String str = new StringBuilder().append("").append('a').toString();
```

in reality.

same goes for integer + string or char + int to string. I think your simpliest way would be to use string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want

`String.valueOf(letter).concat(numbers.toString());`